# Magento 2 : How to get custom module collection in module template file

Tags: magento2, module, resource-model

I want to load custom module collection in module template file :

I have my custom module which has table name:tagdata

I want to load "tagdata" table data in my template file.

And yeah I created a grid with UI component.

Please check my model file :

```
<?php

namespace [vendor]\[module]\Model;

class Extratags extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
{
    function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $resource, $resourceCollection, $data);
    }

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('[vendor]\[module]\Model\ResourceModel\Extratags');
    }
}
```

Comment: You want custom collection in grid or in template file?

Comment: in template file, Grid is successfully created

Comment: You can create model of that custom extension, right? And you have block file of that template file, right?

Comment: yeah you can check my model file in question i just edited

Comment: I posted answer, please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get collection you need to do something like this,

**=> Block File :**

```
 use [vendor]\[module]\Model\ExtratagsFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;

       class Blockclass extends Template
       {
               protected $_modelextratagsFactory;

            public function __construct(Context $context, 
                    ExtratagsFactory $MainmodelextratagsFactory, 
                    array $data = [])
                {
                    $this->_modelextratagsFactory = $MainmodelextratagsFactory;

                    parent::__construct($context, $data);
                }

           public function yourfunction()
           {
              $MyCollection = $this->__modelextratagsFactory->create()
                            ->getCollection();
               return $MyCollection;

           }
        }
```

This is your Block file of your phtml file, and in phtml file you need to call like this,

**=> phtml file :**

```
$collection = $block->yourfunction();
```

Comment: got this error : Fatal error: Cannot access parent:: when current class scope has no parent

Comment: I update answer, please check.

Comment: Above code working fine with my custom module. If above code help you please accept it solution, So it will help other in community.

Comment: after update block file frontend not loaded it's display only loading nothing result. :(

Comment: Check your exception file, I will give you code that working fine with me at many places.

Comment: It's load blank array but i have data in my table.Now how can i load?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51582/discussion-between-dhiren-vasoya-and-sneha-panchal).

Answer (score 1):

You need to create **three files** for getting collection from custom module

> 1) Model, 2) ResourceModel, 3) Collection
>
> Namespace: Prince
>
> Module: Hello
>
> Table: hello

**1) Create Hello.php Model file at**

> app/code/Prince/Helloworld/Model/Hello.php

```
<?php

namespace Prince\Helloworld\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;

class Hello extends AbstractModel
{
    /**
     * Define resource model
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Prince\Helloworld\Model\ResourceModel\Hello');
    }
}
```

**2) Now create Hello.php ResourceModel at**

> app/code/Prince/Helloworld/Model/ResourceModel/Hello.php

```
<?php

namespace Prince\Helloworld\Model\ResourceModel;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb;

class Hello extends AbstractDb
{
    /**
     * Define main table
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('hello', 'id'); //hello is table of module
    }
}
```

**3) Now create Collection.php Collection file at**

> app/code/Prince/Helloworld/Model/ResourceModel/Hello/Collection.php

```
<?php

namespace Prince\Helloworld\Model\ResourceModel\Hello;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;

class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{
    /**
     * Define model & resource model
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(
            'Prince\Helloworld\Model\Hello',
            'Prince\Helloworld\Model\ResourceModel\Hello'
        );
    }
}
```

Now you can test your collection in `Index.php` controller `app/code/Prince/Helloworld/Controller/Index/Index.php`

```
<?php

namespace Prince\Helloworld\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Prince\Helloworld\Model\HelloFactory;

class Index extends Action
{
    protected $_modelHelloFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context, 
        HelloFactory $modelHelloFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_modelHelloFactory = $modelHelloFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {

        $resultPage = $this->_modelHelloFactory->create();
        $collection = $resultPage->getCollection(); //Get Collection of module data
        var_dump($collection->getData());
        exit;

    }
}
```

**If you want to get collection in template using block file**

Another four files you need to add nad create

**1. Block File**

**2. Layout File**

**3. Controller File**

**4. Templarte File**

Create Block file **Hello.php**

```
namespace vendorName\ModuleName\Block\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use vendorName\ModuleName\Model\Hello;

class Hello extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template 
{
    protected $helloModelFactory;
    protected $request;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        Hello $helloModelFactory,
        RequestInterface $request,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_helloModelFactory = $helloModelFactory;
        $this->_request = $request;
    }

    /**
     * Preparing global layout
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareLayout() {
        parent::_prepareLayout();
        $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('Display Collection'));
        return $this;
    }

    public function getHello()
    {
        $collection = $this->_helloModelFactory->getCollection();
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

Or Create Layout file **routName_controllername_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
             <block class="vendorName\ModuleName\Block\Event\Index" name="newevent" template="vendorName_ModuleName::Index.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Create Controller File **Index.php**

```
<?php
namespace vendorName\ModuleName\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action 
{
    /**
     * @param Action\Context $context
     */

    protected $resultPageFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Action\Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    public function execute() {

        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

Create Template file **Index.phtml**

```
<?php

var_dump($block->getgetHello()->getData());
```

I hope it's work for ever