# Magento 2 get custom module data in theme phtml

Tags: magento2, module, collection, resource-model, magento2.1.5

I have created the custom module and inserted all the required fields detail in the database. Now, I want to list all rows in below file path:

I have tried with the `$objectManager`, but direct call `$objectManager` in phtml file is not correct way.

Before post this question I have go through the below answers, but when I run I getting a blank screen.

[How can i get collection of custom module in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/73908/how-can-i-get-collection-of-custom-module-in-magento-2)

[Magento 2 : How to get custom module collection in module template file](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/154167/magento-2-how-to-get-custom-module-collection-in-module-template-file)

**app\design\frontend\Vendor\Theme\Magento_Theme\templates\html/home_page.phtml**

```
<div class="" data-section-name="home">
  <div class="header-section">
    <?php $collection = $block->getCustomoptionmanagerList();
        echo '<pre>'; print_r($collection); die;
    ?>

  </div>
</div>

  <div class="back-top-button"><a href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="top-arrow"></i> TOP</a></div>
```

Model Class code file

**app\code\Vendor\Customoptionmanager\Model/Customoptionmanager.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Customoptionmanager\Model;

class Customoptionmanager extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Vendor\Customoptionmanager\Model\ResourceModel\Customoptionmanager');
    }
}
```

Block file Code:

```
<?php

use Vendor\Customoptionmanager\Model\CustomoptionmanagerFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;

class CustomoptionmanagerList extends Template
{
    protected $_modelCustomoptionmanagerFactory;

    public function __construct(Context $context, 
            CustomoptionmanagerFactory $CustomoptionmanagerList, 
            array $data = [])
        {
            $this->_modelCustomoptionmanagerFactory = $CustomoptionmanagerList;
           parent::__construct($context, $data);
        }

   public function getCustomoptionmanagerList()
   {
      $optionCollection = $this->_modelCustomoptionmanagerFactory->create()->getCollection();
       return $optionCollection;
   }
}
?>
```

Comment: Inject a view model to the block that has template home_page.phtml: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/view-models.html. You can also use a block, but highly not recommended. In any case, the problem here is that you don't have your model available to the template either via a block or view model. You can set the block or view model in the layout.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `HomepageFactory` in dependency injection but you have not put it in use anywhere .
It seems like you want to inject instance of `Vendor\Customoptionmanager\Model\CustomoptionmanagerFactory` which should be done using  `CustomoptionmanagerFactory` in dependency injection .

```
 public function __construct(Context $context, 
            CustomoptionmanagerFactory $CustomoptionmanagerList, 
            array $data = [])
        {
            $this->_modelCustomoptionmanagerFactory = $CustomoptionmanagerList;
           parent::__construct($context, $data);
        }
```

Comment: I have updated the code after your answer, but not solved issue.

Comment: Can you specify the error you're getting?

Comment: I have solved this issue and now it's working fine, Thanks