# Magento 2.3 Show all data from table not working

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

> Block code(path: \magento\app\code\Sample\HelloWorld\Block\Index.php)

```
<?php 
namespace Sample\HelloWorld\Block;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Sample\HelloWorld\Model\PostFactory;

class Index extends Template {
    protected $_postFactory;
    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        PostFactory $postFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_postFactory = $postFactory;
    }
 
    public function getData()
    {
        $post = $this->_postFactory->create();
        $collection = $post->getCollection();
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

> Template file code (path:
> \magento\app\code\Sample\HelloWorld\view\frontend\templates\index.phtml)

```
<?php
/**
 * @var \Sample\HelloWorld\Block\Display $block
 */
?>
<h2>Hello <b>World</b></h2>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th><?= __('Post ID'); ?></th>
        <th><?= __('Name'); ?></th>
        <th><?= __('URL Key'); ?></th>
        <th><?= __('Post Contents'); ?></th>
        <th><?= __('Tags'); ?></th>
        <th><?= __('Status'); ?></th>
        <th><?= __('Updated At'); ?></th>
        <th colspan="2"><?= __('Action'); ?></th>
    </tr>
    <?php
        $collectionData = $block->getData();
        echo($collectionData);
        foreach($collectionData as $collection):
            print_r($collection);
        endforeach;
    ?>
    
    
</table>
```

> Table structure:

[image]

Output is empty page. When I remove all code inside the Index  class and just keep a hello world in the template, The hello world text is showing successfully.

Please help, I can't find the issue in this..

Comment: Can you take the guide from this reference link which shows steps wise process for what you want. https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/how-to-create-crud-model-magento-2.html

Comment: Thanks, It is working in that way. So we need to write code in controller.. Not in block?

Also, If I want to pass the collection to the template, How can I do that..

Answer (score 0):

you are calling data from collection factory so,if you want to print data than you update your code by me code(below).

```
  $collectionData = $block->getData();
    foreach($collectionData as $collection):
        print_r($collection->getData());
    endforeach;
```

Comment: Tried but my template file is not showing any output

Answer (score 0):

You can write function in block class file for fetching a collection and call that function in template file are as below example.

1] Block Class file

```
namespace vendorNanme\ModuleName\Block\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use vendorName\ModuleName\Model\Hello;

class Hello extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template 
{
    protected $helloModelFactory;
    protected $request;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        Hello $helloModelFactory,
        RequestInterface $request,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_helloModelFactory = $helloModelFactory;
        $this->_request = $request;
    }

    /**
     * Preparing global layout
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareLayout() {
        parent::_prepareLayout();
        $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('Display Collection'));
        return $this;
    }

    public function getHello()
    {
        $collection = $this->_helloModelFactory->getCollection();
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

2] Template file (index.phtml)

```
<?php
//This line call the block class get hello function.
var_dump($block->getgetHello()->getData());
```

[For more details you can click me](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/154167/magento-2-how-to-get-custom-module-collection-in-module-template-file)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

But now I just deleted everything from my template file and just added a php echo , nothing is writing in the frontend. I tried echo inside controller, it is working. Where will be the error? I checked layout, block everything.

Comment: Verify your code with this reference link step-wise. https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/view-block-layout-template-magento-2.html